# Weka ArffSaver Not Writing Data

Tags: csv, weka, arff

I am attempting to replicate the csv to arff instructions found [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Converting+CSV+to+ARFF). My code is copied below. The resultant arff prints the attributes section correctly. However, there is nothing under the "@data" section:

Code:

```
public class CsvToArff {
  /**
   * takes 2 arguments:
   * - CSV input file
   * - ARFF output file
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.println("\nUsage: CSV2Arff <input.csv> <output.arff>\n");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // load CSV
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setFieldSeparator(";");
    loader.setNominalAttributes("2,5,8,10");
    loader.setNoHeaderRowPresent(false);
    loader.setSource(new File(args[0]));
    loader.getStructure();
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

    // save ARFF
    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(data);
    saver.setFile(new File(args[1]));
    saver.setDestination(new File(args[1]));
    saver.writeBatch();
  }
}
```

CSV File:

```
PrevPause;PrevPOS;PrevLength;WordPause;WordPOS;WordLength;NextPause;NextPOS;NextLength;Location
625;"JJ";4;156;"NN";4;1234;"FW";1;"OUT"
156;"NN";4;1234;"FW";1;187;"NN";4;"OUT"
1234;"FW";1;187;"NN";4;188;"VBD";3;"OUT"
```

Resultant arff:

```
@relation mwe_pred_debug

@attribute PrevPause numeric
@attribute PrevPOS {JJ,NN,FW}
@attribute PrevLength numeric
@attribute WordPause numeric
@attribute WordPOS {NN,FW}
@attribute WordLength numeric
@attribute NextPause numeric
@attribute NextPOS {FW,NN,VBD}
@attribute NextLength numeric
@attribute Location {OUT}

@data
```

Any idea why the last section is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the setFieldSeparator(String) and setNoHeaderRowPresent(boolean) functions have recently been added to the CSVLoader, and are not currently in the current stable version (3.6).  Perhaps this is something that could be raised with the Weka Development team.

As an alternative, you could change the semi-colons to commas in your csv and process the document as shown in your above tutorial.  The sample appeared to convert correctly using the data sample and tutorial source given in your question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why, if those methods are accessible from my weka.jar, they aren't usable?

Comment: They are usable, however are not in the current stable release.  I am stating only that there may be undocumented issues as a result of these changes, but I tried converting your data and it came through fine.  At least this could serve as a short term solution, but you may be able to raise the issue with the Weka dev team.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It worked great for me using a comma, and getting rid of additional methods. Thank you again.